Instead throwing BSOD nothing happened after clicking button
I tried to write program which throws BSOD after clicking a button in Delphi:
procedure RtlAdjustPrivilege(var Privilege: Integer; var bEnablePrivilege: Boolean; var IsThreadPrivilege: Boolean; var PreviousValue: PBoolean) stdcall; external 'ntdll.dll' name 'RtlAdjustPrivilege';
procedure NtRaiseHardError(var ErrorStatus: UInt64;var NumberOfParameters: UInt64; var UnicodeStringParameterMask: UInt64; var IntPtr: UInt64; var ValidResponseOption: UInt64; var Response: PLongInt) stdcall; external 'ntdll.dll' name 'NtRaiseHardError';

var bl, a, b: Boolean;
var I: Integer;
var Res: LongInt;
var Pb: PBoolean;
var c, d, e, f, g: UInt64;
var PRes: PLongInt;
procedure TForm4.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
     I := 19;
     a := True;
     b := False;
     Pb := @bl;
     RtlAdjustPrivilege(I, a, b, pb);
     c := 3221225595;
     d := 0;
     e := 0;
     f := 0;
     g := 6;
     PRes := @Res;
     NtRaiseHardError(c,d,e,f,g, PRes);
end;

But after clicking button nothing happens, I wonder where I made the mistake, here is the code, I rewrite this answer in Delphi
EDIT:
Now code looks like this, but still nothing
procedure RtlAdjustPrivilege(var Privilege: Integer; var bEnablePrivilege: Boolean; var IsThreadPrivilege: Boolean; var PreviousValue: PBoolean) stdcall; external 'ntdll.dll' name 'RtlAdjustPrivilege';
procedure NtRaiseHardError(var ErrorStatus: UInt64;var NumberOfParameters: UInt64; var UnicodeStringParameterMask: Pointer; var IntPtr: Pointer; var ValidResponseOption: UInt64; var Response: PLongInt) stdcall; external 'ntdll.dll' name 'NtRaiseHardError';

var bl, a, b: Boolean;
var I: Integer;
var Res: LongInt;
var Pb: PBoolean;
var c, d, g: UInt64;
var e, f: Pointer;
var PRes: PLongInt;
procedure TForm4.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
     I := 19;
     a := True;
     b := False;
     Pb := @bl;
     RtlAdjustPrivilege(I, a, b, pb);
     c := $C000007B;
     d := 0;
     e := nil;
     f := nil;
     g := 6;
     PRes := @Res;
     NtRaiseHardError(c,d,e,f,g, PRes);
end;


NtRaiseHardError must not create BSOD but only messagebox. and 3221225595 not redable. compare to C000007B

@RbMm I didn't know if it could have hex there, so I put decimal

So how  it should look like?

@wzzzawzzz you can use the $ prefix for hex literals: c := $C000007B; 

Why cutting the functions down to procedures? Why not looking up how to write numeric literals in Delphi?

@AmigoJack that link about literals is for C++ not Delphi

@RemyLebeau Thanks, but it gives me the same effect, I think problem is elsewhere

@AmigoJack cause I tried to write it on myself  and thught procedures are good :)

@wzzzawzzz "it gives me the same effect" - sure, because the numeric value is the same regardless of which representation you use in the code. The use of hex is just for better readability, it doesn't change the code's behavior

@RemyLebeau same effect I mean nothing happens when I changed it or I didn't understand, sorry.

I changed UnicodeStringParameterMask and IntPtr and gave them nil but still no result

@wzzzawzzz Your declarations of RtlAdjustPrivilege() and NtRaiseHardError() are both completely wrong. Why are you using var parameters for everything? The parameters should be passed in by value, not by reference. Also, you are using a lot of 64bit integers in places where you shouldn't be. Also, both functions have return values that give error codes, but you are ignoring them.

@RemyLebeau those 64bit integer are mistakes, I made wrong assumptions

I'll try rewrite it with just Integers, pointers and boolean / boolean pointers

Okay ErrorStatus must be long :D

Okay should be like this
function RtlAdjustPrivilege(Privilege: Integer; bEnablePrivilege: Boolean; IsThreadPrivilege: Boolean; PreviousValue: PBoolean): Integer stdcall; external 'ntdll.dll' name 'RtlAdjustPrivilege';
function NtRaiseHardError(ErrorStatus: UInt64; NumberOfParameters: Integer; UnicodeStringParameterMask: Pointer; IntPtr: Pointer; ValidResponseOption: Integer; Response: PLongInt): Integer stdcall; external 'ntdll.dll' name 'NtRaiseHardError';

var bl: Boolean;
var Res: LongInt;
procedure TForm4.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
     RtlAdjustPrivilege(19, True, False, @bl);
     NtRaiseHardError($C000007B,0,nil,nil,6,@Res);
end;


Your declarations of RtlAdjustPrivilege() and NtRaiseHardError() are both wrong. You should not be using var parameters for everything. The parameters are expected to be passed in by value, not by reference. Also, you are using a lot of 64bit integers in places where you shouldn't be. Also, both functions have return values that give error codes, but you are ignoring them.
This code BSOD's for me:
uses
  Winapi.Windows;

function RtlAdjustPrivilege(
  Privilege: ULONG;
  bEnablePrivilege: Boolean;
  IsThreadPrivilege: Boolean;
  PreviousValue: PBoolean): NTSTATUS; stdcall; external 'ntdll.dll' name 'RtlAdjustPrivilege';

type
  PHARDERROR_RESPONSE_OPTION = ^HARDERROR_RESPONSE_OPTION;
  HARDERROR_RESPONSE_OPTION = (
    OptionAbortRetryIgnore,
    OptionOk,
    OptionOkCancel,
    OptionRetryCancel,
    OptionYesNo,
    OptionYesNoCancel,
    OptionShutdownSystem
  );

  PHARDERROR_RESPONSE = ^HARDERROR_RESPONSE;
  HARDERROR_RESPONSE = (
    ResponseReturnToCaller,
    ResponseNotHandled,
    ResponseAbort,
    ResponseCancel,
    ResponseIgnore,
    ResponseNo,
    ResponseOk,
    ResponseRetry,
    ResponseYes
  );

function NtRaiseHardError(
  ErrorStatus: NTSTATUS;
  NumberOfParameters: ULONG;
  UnicodeStringParameterMask: Pointer;
  Parameters: Pointer;
  ValidResponseOption: HARDERROR_RESPONSE_OPTION;
  Response: PHARDERROR_RESPONSE): NTSTATUS; stdcall; external 'ntdll.dll' name 'NtRaiseHardError';

const
  STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT = NTSTATUS($C000007B);

var
  bl: Boolean;
  Res: HARDERROR_RESPONSE;
  ret: NTSTATUS;
begin
  RtlAdjustPrivilege(19, True, False, @bl);
  NtRaiseHardError(STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT, 0, nil, nil, OptionShutdownSystem, @Res);
end;


I made this new version and it works, strangely

And boolean is not necessarily winbool either.

@MarcovandeVoort the two APIs in question use BOOLEAN aka BYTE, whereas (WIN)BOOL is int instead. So a pascal boolean should be fine.
